# C++17 std::variant header file (clang 6.0.0)

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, variant

**Update**

I narrowed down the problem to (probably! it's not entirely clear, even reading all I could find about the topic) that installing `stdlibc++-7-dev` would provide me with suitable (i.e., C++17-compliant) STL headers and libraries.

This (also, apparently) comes bundled with Ubuntu 17.04 (`artful`?) but is not available for `xenial` (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) which is what I'm using.

I have tried downloading the individual `.deb` packages and installing them, but it quickly becomes a maze of unresolved dependencies.

If anyone could point me to how to install `libstdc++-7-dev` on 16.04, I'd be most grateful.

**Original question**

I have just installed clang++ 6.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 via the package manager (following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905205/installing-clang-5-0-and-using-c17)) and all seems well: `/usr/bin/clang++-6.0` works just fine, and if I try to use something that only works in C++17 (`non-type template arguments with auto`, see [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html)) it compiles and runs, once I set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++-6.0` -- while it fails when I don't.

So... `clang 6.0` understands C++17 as advertised (doh!) but when I use:

```
#include <variant>
```

the file is not found where I would expect it to be:

```
$ ll /usr/include/clang/6.0.0/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Aug  6 21:32 include -> ../../../lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.0/include
```

or anywhere else I can think of.

Would anyone know (a) whether it's supposed to be there at all and (b) if so, where do I go find it?

**Update**

I have double-checked that I have the latest (I think) `stdc++` library:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++-5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++-5-dev is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and same for `libstdc++-6-dev`; also, I have `libc++-dev`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc++-dev is already the newest version (3.7.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Still, the `variant.h*` file is nowhere to be found.
Anything else I should try?

Comment: Try adding `-stdlib=libc++` to both the compiler and the linker.

Comment: Just a quick question: Does Clang 4.0.0 support C++17 or is it only 6.0? This is the first time I'm hearing about 6.0

Comment: Some parts are supported, but still under the `c++1z` flag (I don't expect this to change until the standard is ratified). I think they've switched to 6 in development as they're getting ready to release 5.

Comment: Clang is a compiler. The standard library is separate.

Comment: @T.C. yes, I get that, my question was, how do I get a C++17-compatible STL? I thought it would come installed with the other packages, but clearly it wasn't.

Comment: @kim366 just found this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support looks like clang-4 supports most features, but a couple only came out with 5.

Comment: @Marco Okay. I just find it weird that there is no mention about Clang 6.0 (http://releases.llvm.org/download.html#4.0.1)

Comment: Anyways, maybe try including `<experimental/variant>`. That's what I was doing with `<optional>`, before I updated my compiler

Comment: Thanks, @kim366, that helped narrow it a bit: I found `/usr/include/c++/5/experimental/` which seems to be the bits supporting C++14 - still no `variant` header in that folder, but now I'm guessing it's a case of tracking down which package adds the header files for the STL to support C++17

Comment: @kim366 There is no such thing as `<experimental/variant>`.

Comment: @T.C. It was worth a try..

Comment: You can update to gcc 7.1 and use libstdc++ through clang.

Comment: Clang 5.0 is about to be released. (probably early September).  6.0 is the next release - probably March 2018.

Comment: @kim366 clang 6 is a dev branch [apt.llvm.org](http://apt.llvm.org/). I'm also confused about how to get c++17 headers. `string_view` is part of the standard now and `experimental/string_view` is from TS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, clang 5.0 (or rather, the libc++ that will ship as part of clang 5) has the `<variant>` header. But you need to be sure that you have installed libc++.

And as @KayEss mentioned, you'll need to pass `-std=c++17` (or the earlier version of the same flag `-std=c++1z`) because variant is a C++17-only feature.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "you need to be sure that you have installed libc++" part? I have installed clang++-6 package (and verified it works fine) along with other packages that were "suggested" by `apt-get`: however, when I looked into the `libstdc++` packages to install, I didn't see anything obvious to install.
(and, yes, I already use the `--std=c++17` flag - but that would fail the compilation: it's the header file that's missing)

Comment: When you install clang for (say) Ubuntu, it comes set up to use the already installed C++ standard library (libstdc++). This is helpful, because it means that you can "mix and match" object files compiled with gcc and clang. You need to install the `libcxx` package as well (example here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libc%2B%2B) and pass `-std=libc++` to clang.